# tableView cell height... how to customize it?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, height

Is it possible to modify height of only one cell in a grouped table view?
I have a table view with 2 sections of 3 and 2 rows... I would change row height of the second row of the second section...

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can look at this method:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

In your case, the code should look like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
      return SPECIAL_HEIGHT;
   }
   return NORMAL_HEIGHT;
}
```

You can look for more details about [the method here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)

Comment: Ok thanks! But I have a problem... If I type a number like return 60.0; works greatly but if I type some code for returning the height based on a UILabel text, cell background don't appear... I added this code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

Comment: else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
  descrizioneLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 285, 50)];
  descrizioneLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
  descrizioneLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  descrizioneLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
  descrizioneLabel.text = wish.descrizione;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:descrizioneLabel];
 }

Comment: and this is the method posted by you: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 
 if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
  NSString *test = descrizioneLabel.text;
  UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
  CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0, MAXFLOAT);
  CGSize labelSize = [testo sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  
  return labelSize.height;
 }
 
 return 44.0;
}

Comment: I am not sure but here is my guess: the method heightForRow is called before the method cellForRow, so at the time you call descrizoneLabel in heightForRow, it is not constructed yet, can you test that. I don't have XCode here

Comment: Ok now I understand... And how can I do to create the label and then call the heightForRow methods? Thanks ;)

Comment: Is it possible to create the label in the viewDidLoad method? Are this method called before the heightForRow method? How can I call tableViewCell from the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: viewDidLoad is always called once when you init the view and you can create the view. you can create the label in viewDidLoad and then call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: I've just created the label in the viewDidLoad method and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I added it to the cell with [cell.contentView addSubview:label] I also added some NSLogs in the heightForRow method and the code works because in the console I see the value! Now the cell change height but I use initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 11, 285, 50) to create the label then if the text is short, the label isn't centred with the cell and it exit from it... how can I retrieve the width and the height of the cell for use it in the initWithFrame method? Thanks :D If you don't understand me I'll email you ;)

Comment: it should be better to email me, it started to be a long comment, `vodkhang@gmail.com`

Comment: Oh I solved the problem buy adding a method that calculate an height based on a text string then in the initWithFrame method I added the returned value :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

In **iOS 8** and above we can use the **Dynamic Table View Cell** Height.

Using this feature `UITableviewCell` get its height from its content and We don't need to write **heightForRowAtIndexPath**

All I have to do in **viewDidLoad()**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

If `cell` contains `uilabel`. then apply constraints to `uilabel`

[image]

Make sure you change Label --Lines-- to 0

[image]

The cell will grow automatically with content of `uilabel`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the following method to return the height for the row at a given index path:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For the indexpath just check for which row and section and adjust the height accordingly