# Why doesn't my UITableView use prototypes for cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

so here is my code and it doesn't work

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier;
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        // buttonCell
        CellIdentifier = @"buttonCell";
        buttonCell *cell = (buttonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.startAddressLabel.text = @"something";

        //cell config
        //debug
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"Cell Identifier: %@", CellIdentifier);

        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        //mutableCaptionCell date&time
        CellIdentifier = @"mutableCaptionCell";
        mutableCaptionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //cell config
        cell.infoLabel.text = @"Время и дата";
        cell.contentLabel.text = @"";

        //debug
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);

        return cell;

    } else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        //mutableCaptionCell tax
        CellIdentifier = @"mutableCaptionCell";
        mutableCaptionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //cell config
        cell.infoLabel.text = @"Тариф";
        cell.contentLabel.text = @"";

        //debug
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);

      return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        //mutableCaptionCell car
        CellIdentifier = @"mutableCaptionCell";
        mutableCaptionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //cell config
        cell.infoLabel.text = @"Выбор машины на карте";
        cell.contentLabel.text = @"";

        //debug
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);

        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        //wishCell wishlist
        CellIdentifier = @"wishCell";
        WishCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //cell config
        cell.infoLabel.text = @"Пожелания";
        cell.contentLabel.text = @"";

        //debug
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);

        return cell;
    } else
    {
        //debug
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mutableCaptionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = @"ERROR CELL";

        //debug
        //NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);

        return cell;

        ;
    }

}
```

I have said subclasses of **UITableViewCell** for each prototype, the reuse identifiers match each prototype, but what I see on runtime looks like the UITableView doesn't use these prototypes. For example, first cell must be huge one with two buttons, but instead it is shown empty. I NSLoged everything, and log show this:

```
2014-02-18 10:13:51.587 app[1624:70b] indexPath.row: 0
2014-02-18 10:13:51.590 app[1624:70b] Cell Identifier: buttonCell
2014-02-18 10:13:51.594 app[1624:70b] cell: <buttonCell: 0x8b95e00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b96000>>
2014-02-18 10:13:51.600 app[1624:70b] indexPath.row: 1
2014-02-18 10:13:51.603 app[1624:70b] indexPath.row: 2
2014-02-18 10:13:51.606 app[1624:70b] indexPath.row: 3
2014-02-18 10:13:51.610 app[1624:70b] indexPath.row: 4
```

but still TableView doesn't use correct prototypes.

I'm trying to use dynamic prototypes as I need to change some cells height at runtime, may be there is a way to do so with static cells ?

> Sidenote: Im using Xcode 5 for iOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to use Static Cells if the number of cells are limited. When ever we scroll the tableview the cells will get laid again and again. the time taken will be very less and whatever the cell it picks up, it shows the same height to all the cells...I suggest to go for static cells or ever different tableviews if possible....

Comment: I used static cells on previous iteration, but now I need to change height of some cells at runtime as I mentioned above. Is there a way to do so? One of the cells will lead to a different scene with list of options and I should display chosen options back on that cell, so the height must be changed

Comment: This might help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737218/tableview-cell-height-how-to-customize-it

Comment: thank for your help too, Im turning back to static cells solution, because solution with .xibs while using storyboard seems wrong to me, this shouldn't be: as they implemented storyboard all work must be done with storyboard

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that, you are not initializing your cell, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` isn't just enough. It reuses already created cells, so you should first allocate `cell` if dequeue results in `nil`.

Possibly:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    // buttonCell
    CellIdentifier = @"buttonCell";
    buttonCell *cell = (buttonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


   if(!cell)
   {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

    cell.startAddressLabel.text = @"something";

    //cell config
    //debug
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Cell Identifier: %@", CellIdentifier);

    return cell;
}
```

Or load cell designed using IB:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    // buttonCell
    CellIdentifier = @"buttonCell";
    buttonCell *cell = (buttonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


   if(!cell)
   {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];   // Assign reuseIdentifier from IB
   }

    cell.startAddressLabel.text = @"something";

    //cell config
    //debug
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Cell Identifier: %@", CellIdentifier);

    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: many sources say that its not necessary anymore to check if cell is actually created, anyways, your answer didn't work, sorry

Comment: You don't need to do that anymore ;) since iOS 5 or 6 it is guaranteed to return a valid (I.e. Initialized) cell. [As per doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:): `Return Value
A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This method always returns a valid cell.`

Comment: Ok, so it returns a valid cell, but `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier` should be called first: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: give this a try then.

Comment: Not if you are using storyboards ;)

Comment: Im using Storyboard, so I don't have these .nib files, should I still use the method?

Comment: No. I never used them.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245969/in-a-storyboard-how-to-make-a-custom-cell-for-use-with-multiple-controllers

Comment: looks like using a separate .xib for cell is the answer, but logically it is so strange: shouldn't storyboard does this automatically? thanks for answers, guys, I'll try to use separate .xibs now

Comment: @NeverHopeless using separate .xib helped me, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @NeverHopeless now I have another issue: table shows my prototyped cells, but it doesn't resize it, so I see default-sized cells with partial view of my content in it, can you please help ?

Comment: to control cell height you should really handle it with data source have a look at my suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396907/how-to-programmatically-increase-uitableview-cells-height-in-iphone/21398774#21398774