# how to edit some Row height in tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview

I have 15 rows in tableview this table are dynamic table but I want row 5 and 11 to height 20(This is a topic menu in slide menu). I edit in story board but it doesn't change.

Comment: use `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737218/tableview-cell-height-how-to-customize-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the conditions over here :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 5){
         return 20;
    }
    else{
         return 71.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath;
{
   CGFloat rowHeight = 10.0;

   if(0 == indexPath.section && (5 == indexPath.row || 11 == indexPath.row))
   {
      rowHeight = 20.0;
   }

   return rowHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set default height in `storyboard`(which is more likely to be used) and if you want to return different heights for each cell than you should use the below `delegate` method of `UITableView` and incorporate the conditions for returning the height of `UITableViewCell's` based on your requirement(in your case the requirement is to return the height of row 5th and 11th as 20 else for other rows some height, lets assume 50). You can do so as -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if(indexPath.row == 5 || indexPath.row == 11)
         return 20.0;
    else
         return 50.0;
}
```