# Swift/XCode 6.4: how to programmatically change the height of cells in table view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

In my iOS app there is a table view controller of static cells containing three different types of cells whose style is Subtitle. One of these should be much higher than the other two because it is supposed to contain a very long text. So, in its size inspector I set an height of 100 but when I create a new cell in the code through its identifier, then the height is always the default one.

How can I change it? I've read that I should override this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100 //Whatever fits your need for that cell
}
```

but then I don't know how to use it. 
Can you explain please?
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [tableView cell height... how to customize it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737218/tableview-cell-height-how-to-customize-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said that you `tableview` cells' are statics, so you know that which cell is having more height, pass the `indexpath` of that cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath and return the expected height of cell from there.
Suppose your 1st cell is having more height, then use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            return 100 //Whatever fits your need for that cell
        } else {
            return 50 // other cell height
        }
}
```

No need to create three different prototype cell, just create on cell that will be sufficient.

Comment: Oh, it works, thank you. But why can't I set this through the storyboard? It would be much easier... forgive my ignorance, I'm very new to ios and xcode and swift. Please explain me if you want

Comment: have you use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in your code.

Comment: yes, I've just used it and it works...I was just wondering why setting the storyboard was not enough and why also that method is needed

Comment: in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you have just used the single cell, thats why you are getting the same cell.For debugging just set the cell background color in your storyboard, you will see the same color for all your cells.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as you mentioned in you post and get the cell with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Then set the height depending on the `reuseIdentifier`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    if cell.reuseIdentifier == "SpecialCell" {
      return 100.0
    }
  }
  return 44.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 2 different TableViewCells in Interface builder and choose the right one to use in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

That's the easiest way and you can even differentiate more between the 2 types when it's necessary.

Comment: Ehm, that's what I did. Look at my question, I have uploaded a screenshot.  I have 3 different TableViewCells... the last one is bigger but it's completely ignored. I think I am missing some setting in the storyboard...or maybe some silly error. Is is right?

Comment: are you using the correct prototype cell ? You're probable loading the same one each time

Comment: I think so because I call it with the correct identifier. Or what do you mean exactly?