# tableviewCell is cut off from bottom in every cell

Tags: ios, cell, uitableview

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 140))

    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    whiteRoundedView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    whiteRoundedView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.clipsToBounds = true;
}
```

Every cell is cut off from the bottom and not showing the complete cell structure.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Let me know if the image is not showing up. I am new to swift. So if you need any more info on this let me know.

Comment: have you tried increasing the height of the cell?

Comment: Reduce the height of `whiteRoundedView` OR Increase the height of cell-content view.

Comment: this screen shot is from simulator ? or real device @GauravRathi

Comment: What is the height of cell?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: The screenshot is from Simulator. But on the real device also this is same.

Comment: @Jeevan: Let me try that. Can you please paste the code to do so?

Comment: @jegadeesh: How to increase height of the cell?

Comment: @byJeevan: It worked Thanks. I reduced the height of whiteRoundedView to 40 at the time on initialization/

Comment: @GauravRathi refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737218/tableview-cell-height-how-to-customize-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough space for the `whiteRoundedView` over cell height.

Hence, reduce the height <140 of `whiteRoundedView` while initialization.

`let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width:self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: YOUR_NEW_HEIGHT))`

Answer (score 0):

Your `whiteRoundedView` should be within the cell content view.

So, try using `heightForRowAt indexPath` and use the same height for `whiteRoundedView` in your `willDisplay cell`